# Tipos de conversiones en C#

Tags: c#

¿Qué diferencia hay entre estos tipos de conversiones?

```
    string nombre = "1234";
    int i = (int)nombre;

    string nombre = "1234";
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(nombre);

    string nombre = "1234";
    int i = Int32.Parse(nombre);
```

¿Hay establecido algún tipo de regla para utilizar una u otra? Alguna vez me encuentro con que si intento realizar una conversión con alguna de ellas no me deja y en cambio probando con cualquiera de las otras si...
Nunca me ha quedado claro cuando hay que utilizar unas u otras.
La información que obtengo indagando es bastante confusa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes que todo, eso no son comparaciones sino *conversiones* (casting) de datos.

> ¿Hay establecido algún tipo de regla para utilizar una u otra?

Si. Aqui las explico para ti:

```
string nombre = "1234";
int i = (int)nombre;
```

A esto se le llama [Conversion Explicita](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8s682k58(v=vs.90).aspx)(explicit casting). Este tipo de conversion se utiliza cuando le especificas explicitamente a que tipo de datos quieres convertir un objeto. En tu ejemplo, estas claramente expresando que quieres convertir un objeto `System.String` a `System.Int32`.

Para poder hacer una conversion explicita tienen que cumplirse 2 condiciones:  que exista algun tipo de relacion entre el objeto y el tipo de dato a convertir, esto sea por herencia o por la implementacion de una interfaz en común o sobre cargando el [operador de conversion explicita](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjcq-yN2_PVAhXEv1QKHbJtB7UQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fes-es%2Flibrary%2Fms228498(v%3Dvs.90).aspx&usg=AFQjCNEMtSzoecjZ_LXsW7p2EHhi3TmYEA) o [implicita](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

La structura `System.Int32(int)` es un ejemplo de la sobrecarga del operador implicito con el tipo de dato `char` ya que puedes convertir un `char` a `int`  sin tener que especificarle el tipo de dato a convertir:

```
char n = 'n'
int letra = n; // valido
```

Mientras que para convertir de `int` a `char` tienes que especificarlo de manera explicita:

```
int nNumber= 110;
char n = (char)nNumber;
```

En tu ejemplo, la operacion no es valida porque no se cumplen ninguna de las 2 condiciones.

---

```
string nombre = "1234";
int i = Convert.ToInt32(nombre);
```

Convert.ToInt32 convierte un objeto `int`, `long`, `decimal`, `bool`, `char`, `float`, `byte`, `DateTime` a `System.Int32`. Si el tipo de dato no se puede convertir a `int` se lanza una excepcion `FormatException`.

---

```
string nombre = "1234";
int i = Int32.Parse(nombre);
```

Convierte un `System.String` a `Int32`. Si el tipo de dato no se puede convertir a `int` se lanza una excepcion `FormatException`.

La unica diferencia entre estos 2 ultimos es la variedad de sobrecargas que `Convert.Int32` ofrece.

Answer (score 3):

En el caso de tu ejemplo, la respuesta corta es: son lo mismo, pero dependiendo del argumento será su comportamiento.

Estas son las definiciones y diferencias que encontré. Sería interesante que publicaras algún ejemplo donde no puedes comparar:

**Conversión Unboxing**

> Es una conversión explítica del tipo object a un tipo de valor o de un
>   tipo de interfaz a un tipo de valor que implementa la interfaz. [Conversión unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b95fkada(v=vs.80).aspx).

```
string nombre = "1234";
    int i = (int)nombre;
```

- Es costoso en rendimiento
- Si se aplica a un argumento null o a un valor incompatible producirá InvalidCastException.

**Casting (Parsing) Int32.Parse**

> Convierte la representación en forma de cadena a un numero en el entero de 32 bits con signo equivalente.[Método Int32.Parse (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Retorna ArgumentNullException cuando el argumento es null
- Se recomienda en su lugar usar [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) para evitar excepciones, devuelve un Boolean que indica si se hizo correctamente la conversión o no.

**Conversión Convert.ToInt32()**

> Convierte un valor especificado en un entero de 32 bits con signo. [Método Convert.ToInt32()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx)

- Retorna cero cuanto el argumento es null
- Convert.ToInt32(string) implementa internamente int.Parse()
- Convert.ToInt32(object) implementa ((IConvertible) value).ToInt32

**Otras Fuentes:**

[Whats is the difference between int parse and convert toint32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32)
[Is casting the same as converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143997/is-casting-the-same-thing-as-converting)
[What is the differnce between boxing unboxing and type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085144/what-is-the-difference-between-boxing-unboxing-and-type-casting)

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia es la posibilidad de perdida de datos, por precisión.

si no se puede realizar una conversión sin riesgo de perder información, el compilador requiere que se realice una conversión explícita, que se denomina conversión. Una conversión de tipos es una manera de informar explícitamente al compilador de que se pretende realizar la conversión y se es consciente de que se puede producir pérdida de datos.

En las conversiones implícitas no se requiere ninguna sintaxis especial porque la conversión tiene seguridad de tipos y no se perderá ningún dato.

Las conversiones explícitas requieren un operador de conversión. La conversión es necesaria si es posible que se pierda información en la conversión, o cuando es posible que la conversión no sea correcta por otros motivos.